# List in Java, store list in list

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to store some number of List like,

```
[1,2,3,[5,6],7,[8,[9,3,4]],4]
```

in java.

I try Array List for my code, but I don't know how I can assign this type of List in java.

So how can we directly assign this type of list/arrays in java?

Comment: That seems to be a list of a mix of both numbers and lists of the same type. That's not a type that Java supports. You can have a `List<Object>` and just throw in whatever you like, but there won't be any type safety for this. Could you explain what those values *mean* semantically? Maybe there's a data structure that's better-suited for representing them in Java. This might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I Just need this type input for my Competitive Program. As you mention `List<Object>` i just  try it and it works fine, But is there any better solution for this. List<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(5);
        array.add(2);
        array.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7,-1)));
        array.add(3);
        array.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(6,new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-13,8)),4)));

Comment: I do not understand the down-votes on this Question.

Comment: @Nikk Posting the content of your comment as an edit to your Question might stave off further down-votes.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
List<Object> list = List.of( 1, 2, 3, List.of( 5, 6 ), 7, List.of( 8, List.of( 9, 3, 4 ) ), 4 );
```

> [1, 2, 3, [5, 6], 7, [8, [9, 3, 4]], 4]

## Details

The title of your question is misleading. You are not trying to add a list to a list. You are apparently adding some integers to a list as well as adding some lists to the list, and then also adding a list of lists of integers.

So you are mixing types: `Integer` and `List<Integer>`. Then you complicate it further by nesting another list mixing `Integer` and `List<Integer>`.

When specifying the type a `List` should hold, you can only specify *one* type, not two.

Either a list of integers:

```
List< Integer > list = List.of( 1, 2, 3, 7, 4 ) ;
```

… or a list of lists of integers:

```
List< List< Integer > > list = List.of( List.of( 5 , 6 ), List.of( 9, 3, 4 ) ) ;
```

You cannot mix the two, not while specifying the type constraint defining the list. Some specialized language might support this, but not Java.

The workaround in Java is to use `List< Object >`. See the first part of the excellent [Answer by supernova](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199068/642706). But you lose [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
List<Object> list = List.of( 1, 2, 3, List.of( 5, 6 ), 7, List.of( 8, List.of( 9, 3, 4 ) ), 4 );
```

> list.toString(): [1, 2, 3, [5, 6], 7, [8, [9, 3, 4]], 4]

As [Sauer commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68196438/list-in-java-store-list-in-list/68199036?noredirect=1#comment120528370_68196438), you mignt have a larger design problem. Fixing that problem might eliminate this nested mixing of types.

Comment: Despite the code looks a bit nicer there's some caveat to it: List.of() is newer and was introduced later in Java 9 (if I'm remembering right). Just s there's some people stuck in 8. Despite that it has pro's and cons:
First of all it's immutable. So when someone asks for Lists I usually assume he wants to modify it later on (otherwise an array would in almost all cases be the better choice).  Secondly null element cannot be handled.  Fully agree to the design problem comment ;-)

Comment: @supernova I used `List.of` for brevity, not really important here. The Question does not specify a version of Java, nor does the Question involve nulls. And it is generally best to start with immutable data until you determine mutability is required; again, not specified in the Question. Arrays are inflexible, so some of us generally default to using lists and sets rather than arrays unless very large amounts of data are involved. To each, his own.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think List.of tries a cast at compiler time, thus not being able to create multi dimensional structure. All needs to be same depth. e.g.:
List listOfLists = List.of(1,2,3, List.of(5,6), 7, List.of(8, List.of(9,3,4))); should fail. For any iother use cases I'd say it's  best design as most transportable through different data structures, so got my upvote ;-)

Comment: @supernova I too assumed mixing nested `List.of` would fail. That is one reason I pointed the reader to [your amazing Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199068/642706). But, no, it works! I copied your example while adding a generics declaration of `<Object>`. See that code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/E3hOb7).

Comment: Sounds good. Still would prefer to use either plain arrays of all is there at the start or the Arrays.asList() for mutable data. Anything in between is a trade off IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve exactly what you have asked for you can do the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    // [1,2,3,[5,6],7,[8,[9,3,4]],4]

    private void option1(){

        List<Object> listOfLists = Arrays.asList(
                1,
                2,
                3,
                Arrays.asList(5, 6),
                7,
                Arrays.asList(
                        8,
                        Arrays.asList(9, 3, 4)
                ),
                4
        );
        deepPrint(listOfLists);
    }


    private void option2(){

        List<Object> listOfLists = new LinkedList<Object>() {{
            add(1);
            add(2);
            add(3);
            add(new LinkedList<Object>(){{
                add(5);
                add(6);
            }});
            add(7);
            add(new LinkedList<Object>(){{
                add(8);
                add(new LinkedList<Object>(){{
                    add(9);
                    add(3);
                    add(4);
                }});
            }});
            add(4);
        }};

                List<Integer> llist = new LinkedList<Integer>() {{
                    add(2);
                    add(4);
                } };


        Arrays.asList(
                1,
                2,
                3,
                Arrays.asList(5, 6),
                7,
                Arrays.asList(
                        8,
                        Arrays.asList(9, 3, 4)
                ),
                4
        );
        deepPrint(listOfLists);
    }



    private void deepPrint(Object o){
        if(o instanceof Integer || o instanceof Long){
            System.out.print(o);
        }
        else if(o instanceof List){
            System.out.print("[");
            boolean printComma = false;
            for (Object element : (List)o){
                if(printComma){
                    System.out.print(",");
                }
                else{
                    printComma = true;
                }
                deepPrint(element);
            }
            System.out.print("]");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.option1();
        System.out.println("");
        e.option2();
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
[1,2,3,[5,6],7,[8,[9,3,4]],4]
[1,2,3,[5,6],7,[8,[9,3,4]],4]
```

If you know what's the input and how many dimensions (=nesting levels) you have, you could use a multi-dimensional Array with max count per dimension (option1) - or if you have all input available from the get go you can directly instantiate the array in full (see option2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Example2 {
    // [1,
    // 2,
    // 3,
    // [5,6],
    // 7,
    // [8,[9,3,4]],
    // 4]
    private void option1(){
        int[][][]myArray = new int[7][2][3];
        myArray[0][0][0] = 1;
        myArray[1][0][0] = 2;
        myArray[2][0][0] = 3;
        myArray[3][0][0] = 5;
        myArray[3][1][0] = 6;
        myArray[4][0][0] = 7;
        myArray[5][0][0] = 8;
        myArray[5][1][0] = 9;
        myArray[5][0][1] = 3;
        myArray[5][0][2] = 4;
        myArray[6][0][0] = 4;
        printArray(myArray);

    }


        private void option2(){
            int[][][]myArray = {
                    {{1}},
                    {{2}},
                    {{3}},
                    {{5}, {6}},
                    {{7}},
                    {{8}, {9, 3, 4}},
                    {{4}}
        };
        printArray(myArray);
    }


    private void printArray(int[][][] myArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < myArray[j].length; k++) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("array[%d][%d][%d] = %d", i,j,k,myArray[i][j][k]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            Example2 e = new Example2();
            e.option1();
            System.out.println("-----------");
            e.option2();
    }
}
```

There's other more elegant ways to model problems so casting and complex object nesting is not needed.